# Creating argument to filter multiple NID's in a single filter-criteria

Tags: views

I'm having a rather simple Views issue in Drupal 7, Views version 3.11.7

I'm creating a View of Node-teasers so I need to filter it by the desired nodes NID's.

As you could see in the following image, I just typed their numbers but surly nothing happened.

What should I type there that the filter would work?

[image]

Comment: This might help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/105741/how-to-pass-multiple-id-in-drupal-7-view-filter

Comment: i didn't try it but i think you should try Answer number 2 by "Anil Sagar" that is well explained.

Comment: I've read there and tried to implement Answer 2 = I've opened such a contextual filter "NID", and gave it "allow multiple values". Afterwards I clicked save, but at the preview I still see only the first NID from "Sort criteria" (NID=11 FROM 11+26+30+59). I didn't see the other ones as well :\ any ideas?

Comment: Now you will give the NID's in the URL ie example.com/test-view/1,2 and it will gives you two results, 1 and 2 is the NID's.

Comment: You could add a field "Promoted to my view", checkbox. Filter by that in your view. You're promoting them manually anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I created a Contextual filter **based on NID**, And configured it as "fixed value",  gave the values as #+#+#+#+#, and than went to "more" and clicked "allow multiple values". Please see pic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Contextual filter" solution is only needed if you wish to filter your results dynamicly by passing the necessary filters through the URL.

If I understand your question correctly you wish to filter your view on 4 specific nid's only (witch will never change)?

In that case you could modify your views filter setup and split into 4 seperate filters (each filtering on 1 nid). In the dropdown menu (where you have the "add" button to add a new filter) you have a config page where you can rearrange your filters and more importantly you can specify conditionals using filter group's. In your case I would create a second filter group for the 4 nid filters and use the "Or" operator between them.

Comment: Hey, I just want the view to show teasers of these 4 nodes (Maybe I'll add some more nodes in the near future). I do look for the shortest way to do so... I don't want to create a filter for each node but rather to make one filter that will include all of the NID's in one piece.

Comment: Sorry you'll never find a solution where all nid's are in one filter. What you could do however is installing Nodequeue and filter your view on the nodes present in your nodequeue. This has the added bonus that you don't need to modify your view to include or exclude future nodes.